# Why mysql user defined variable is not work in python?

Tags: python, mysql, variables, caching, mysql-workbench

I have a `SQL` ran in python and workbench and both of them return different result. I believe the main cause is because the `@user defined variable` doesn't cache when I pass it to `python mysql connector`, so it cannot do the counting function. Basically, the logic of the `SQL` is to rank the food in each supermarket(group) and return the first 10 food in each supermarket (example only). In workbench, the counter will output `1,2,3,4...` while in python they return `1` which doesn't do the counting. How can I prevent it? Thanks!

```
Code:
    cnx= mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = f'''SELECT supermarket, food, counter
            FROM (
            SELECT supermarket, food, 
                @counter:=IF(@supermarket_id= supermarket, @counter+1,1) as counter, 
                @supermarket_id:= supermarket
            FROM supermkt_data 
            order by supermarket, food) tmp
            WHERE counter<= 10;
            '''
    log.info(query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    result = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the variables. If not then they are treated as constants which are not changed during query execution.

```py
query = f'''SELECT supermarket, food, counter
            FROM ( SELECT supermarket, food, 
                          @counter:=IF(@supermarket_id=supermarket,@counter+1,1) counter, 
                          @supermarket_id:=supermarket
                   FROM supermkt_data 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @supermarket_id:=0, @counter:=0) init_vars
                   ORDER BY supermarket, food) tmp
            WHERE counter <= 10;
         '''
```

Adjust starting values for variables if needed.